# jQuery.csv() plugin unknown error

Tags: javascript, jquery

***Warning: wall of text***

I am using the jQuery.csv plugin to load a csv into an array. It worked just fine, until recently. I dont know if anything has changed, but instead of working, it displays the following error in the console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object function (a,b){return new c.fn.init(a,b)} has no method 'csv'
```

I am calling it (the same way I was before) using the method described in the plugin documentation:

```
jQuery.get(csvfile, function(data) { array = jQuery.csv()(data); });
```

the plugin file itself is very short:

```
    /* Usage:
    *  jQuery.csv()(csvtext)               returns an array of arrays representing the CSV     text.
    *  jQuery.csv("\t")(tsvtext)           uses Tab as a delimiter (comma is the default)
    *  jQuery.csv("\t", "'")(tsvtext)      uses a single quote as the quote character instead of double quotes
 *  jQuery.csv("\t", "'\"")(tsvtext)    uses single & double quotes as the quote character
 */
;
jQuery.extend({
    csv: function(delim, quote, linedelim) {
        delim = typeof delim == "string" ? new RegExp( "[" + (delim || ","   ) + "]" ) : typeof delim == "undefined" ? ","    : delim;
        quote = typeof quote == "string" ? new RegExp("^[" + (quote || '"'   ) + "]" ) : typeof quote == "undefined" ? '"'    : quote;
        lined = typeof lined == "string" ? new RegExp( "[" + (lined || "\r\n") + "]+") : typeof lined == "undefined" ? "\r\n" : lined;

        function splitline (v) {
            // Split the line using the delimitor
            var arr  = v.split(delim),
                out = [], q;
            for (var i=0, l=arr.length; i<l; i++) {
                if (q = arr[i].match(quote)) {
                    for (j=i; j<l; j++) {
                        if (arr[j].charAt(arr[j].length-1) == q[0]) { break; }
                    }
                    var s = arr.slice(i,j+1).join(delim);
                    out.push(s.substr(1,s.length-2));
                    i = j;
                }
                else { out.push(arr[i]); }
            }

            return out;
        }

        return function(text) {
            var lines = text.split(lined);
            for (var i=0, l=lines.length; i<l; i++) {
                lines[i] = splitline(lines[i]);
            }
            return lines;
        };
    }
});
```

i am using jQuery.noConflict() thusly:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
     jQuery.noConflict();
</script>   
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $path ?>/js/jquery.csv.js"></script> 
<script type="text/Javascript" src="<?php echo $path ?>/js/script.js"></script>
```

what i can gather is that the plugin is trying to use .extend to add the function 'csv' to the jQuery object, and that it is not working. has anyone seen/solved this issue? im assuming also that there was a recent change to 1.5.1, but changing to 1.5.2 doesnt change anything.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Works fine on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CmTkC/1/) with jQuery 1.5.1.

Make sure that your statement is wrapped in an 'onload' block.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
     ...
     ...
     jQuery.get(csvfile, function(data) { array = jQuery.csv()(data); });
});
```

Also, I see that you are using PHP to reference the path to the CSV plugin file.  Make sure that the path output from PHP is still valid.

Comment: the paths are valid, i did check that. and it is being called in a function which is being called in the onload.

Comment: though adding the code for the plugin to the onload fixed the problem. so thats something. thanks :)